# How to convert strings to a list in R

Tags: r, string, list, type-conversion

I have a lot of strings (thousands) that I want to make them elements of a list, such as my_list = as.list() so I can call them by index such as my_list[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty7GU.jpg) etc. I have tried

```
my_string = "MTX3, ZNF623, VEPH1, GCLM, ALS2, MAP3K3, CRIP3, GNL2, RAPGEFL1, RAD54B, GCDH, WASF1, PLEKHA2, TNFRSF21, CNNM3, GTF2E2, SNHG5, NTNG1, CHL1-AS2, PALM2-AKAP2, FGFBP3, DHRSX, LNPEP, ISY1, MTERF3, ZNF780A, CCDC24, MCHR1, GTF2H1, AURKA, TYRO3, SLC31A1, RARA, NKD2, SLC25A24, AC087477.2, EID2B, NCALD, TYW3, LUZP1, VXN, RECQL4, AC027307.2, TAF1, ZFP91, TCOF1, GCLC, PPP1R12A, SLC22A18, ZNF28, AC078846.1, TMEM109, MAIP1, TRPC5OS, AEBP2, PGAM2, PPARD, TENT4A, RGS20, ANKRD35, RGS3, VPS53, MMP2, UBE2O, NUMB, AC092069.1, ARHGEF10, AURKB, TSEN54, MLPH, GPATCH8, SMURF1, TBC1D1, SNX7, AC118549.1, PRPS1, HIST2H2BE, KATNAL1, MCL1, BCL7A, SOCS4, ADPGK, ZNF667, CSNK1G3, FBXO45, APEX2, ADRA2B, SNAPC3, MIPEP, DISC1, SCAF11, AC010198.2, ZSCAN16, HPS1, ST7-AS1, SHKBP1, AC012615.1, ACKR3, FER, OSBPL7, SEC11C, SLC1A5, ZBTB44, RPUSD2, ME1, RIN2, STRN3, VIPAS39, KIF20A, PPM1M, ELMOD3, CTR9, TTC30A, TAF4, ASCC1, TOMM40L, ZNF853, SBF2, ABCF1, CXorf38, KDM3B, PLTP, SNX29, VLDLR, MEOX2, PPM1J, CLN3, UBQLN1, NIP7, ANKLE2, ZNF761, GTF3C3, VANGL2, POLR3F, ZCCHC9, NPAS2, HAS2, HS3ST3A1, METTL2B, USP40, AL139289.2, GDF15, MCMBP, UBOX5, C2orf81, LINC01551, TOE1, CA8, SRXN1, RNF207, KIAA0556, IL1R1, GID4, MAMLD1, ZNF319, ZBTB8A, CCDC58, STK32B, IL31RA, PM20D2, TEX2, RFX7, CAMK2N2, JPT1, PGGHG, PCDHB10, MRS2, KAT14, ZNF426, TCAF1, ZBTB45, DPH3, VPS37A, DLX1, YAF2, PACRGL, MED12L, NBPF11, AC026979.2, HSPA14.1, NR2E1, CACNA1E, RIPPLY1, TBX15, AC079922.2, PRPSAP2, ALAS1, TRIM32, MAP11, RTF1, NAP1L3, PPHLN1, GFOD2, AK4, DNAJB5, IMMP2L, NOP2, CRB2, SNHG18, ZNHIT6, CKAP2, SMAD4, ZNF140, BDH1, RFWD3, DYRK1A, ALDH4A1, IFI27, CCNO, DIPK1A, ZNHIT2, LARGE1, ALDH1L1-AS2, DCP1A, HMMR, DHRS7B, GALNT5, INPP5E, FRG1, FGFR3, CLK4, LONRF1, SHF, RFX2, ZNF385D, ZSCAN32, P4HA1, ZCCHC17, MIR34AHG, NSMCE4A, HJURP, BMPR1A, SAMD11, PSMB10, UBE2W, AC092119.3, SEC24D, LINC00662, CASP7, MBTD1, TMEM163, TPM3, TMEM126B, AKT3-IT1, FAM50B, TRAIP, SOX1-OT, PIK3CA, AP3M2, RNF111, RERGL, AZIN1-AS1, PTPN14, CRYBG3, RNF123, IGSF9B, EBF2, GTPBP2, SETD4, PFKP, MED22, IL11, METTL23, ZFPM1, C16orf95, SF3B5, ARHGEF4, HTRA3, TTC28, NTRK3, POLR3E, KLC2, STRBP, NLE1, AC234582.1, ARHGEF11, CFAP44, MAPK7, SLC35A3, RIT2, NKAIN3-IT1, MROH6, MBD1, CUL2, HABP4, USPL1, LIG1, SMARCA2, ITPRIPL1, AC104964.4, KLHL8, LHFPL2, CDC42SE1, NUF2, SLC35E3, INSIG2, ZNF20, RBSN, TEPSIN, UNC119, THSD1, RORB, MCTP1, ZNF668, RFC1, IFI6, MRPL45, KLHL29, TTC39B, SEC22A, IKZF4, CHAF1A, NCKAP5L, OGFRL1, NET1, C17orf75, SLC7A1, PROX1, GEMIN5, ST7, IRF2BP1, MEGF10, NUP37, TYSND1, DYRK4, POLA2, AIM2, JMJD4, PHLDB3, KLF12, KCTD6, ERMAP, NPR2, LRRC42, NFIC, PRKAR1B, MFSD14C, NR2F1-AS1, SRGAP2, THOC2, HYMAI, FBXO46, TBC1D15, FZD2, CYP7B1, HOXA6, CDK7, FBXO25, ATP10B, BTD, ATIC, TMEM245, FAM229A, INF2, FAM207A, GINS1, SOCS6, ILRUN, STXBP4, GAREM2, XKR8, APOLD1, CDH10, TMEM265, ZSCAN5A, ICK, E2F1, NR1H4, CTPS2, NELL2, CEP41, NIF3L1, HAUS1, AC018521.5, AVL9, AC010649.1, BAIAP2L1, ST7L, AVEN, HSPA12A, SGIP1, C12orf49, ARMC9, MRPS30, PYGO1, C19orf54, TSTD3, ZNF544, HAUS6, RAB32, TSPAN10, GALE, PRUNE1, LRRC37A3, SOCS7, TRUB1, TRIM13, SEC23A, MED4, C1orf53, RBMS2, QSOX2, ORC3, CEND1, PLVAP, RSRP1, STXBP3, RAD54L2, PHLPP2, BX255925.3, RNF135, RNF41, SCAMP2, ATL2, DHX29, RFX3, SMYD2, PARP16, RAB4B, ADAMTS13, SMYD3, DHRS12, PIAS4, DIP2C, CCN4, ZCCHC8, TEAD3, RC3H2, OAS3, GPR173, FGGY, ISCA1, TSPO, GAPVD1, NDUFAF7, ZNF691, CDC7, ADCY9, UBAP1L, MRRF, PHAX, CNIH2, RPS6KB1, SMC6, NOP9, SP3, LMO7, JUP, TMEM8B, CEP131, PCGF1, TYW1, TMOD1, RNASE4, LRRC28, RFK, HSPB11, ALKBH4, HNMT, MYLK, GLIPR1L2, BNIP2, PPME1, NPAS1, MPPE1, SOX9-AS1, TRIM44, ZNF106, CARMIL1, CISD2, SLC41A2, ASL, THNSL2, METAP2, LINC00323, ZNF217, FBXW4, YAE1, EXD3, SESN1, GAL3ST1, TMEM80, GNL3L, TBC1D13, INTS8, SLITRK5, WDR20, THBD, TLR4, CNTNAP3B, KLK10, NEK2, NDUFAF6, LPCAT4, ZNF398, TMEM104, PPP4R3B, FARS2, PDGFRL, C17orf80, EBLN3P, CCNY, TRIM25, CALHM2, NR1H3, LIMD1, HOMER3, LRRC8D, BTBD10, CHST11, ZNF136, ZADH2, ERCC6L2, ZNF74, CAPS, TRIM37, ACBD3, PIGP, POLR3K, PIGB, CCDC138, ZNF582-AS1, AGER, TIMELESS, VPS36, HAX1, GPRASP2, KIF14, ABCB7, HOXC4, RBM47, TXNL1, TP53INP2, AHNAK2, SFRP1, AGBL3, UBXN11, CEP76, PKDCC, IRS1, EHD4, ZBTB9, AGL, ABITRAM, FBXW9, TMCO4, BAG2, PTPRD-AS1, MAP1A, STARD4, POLR3G, UTP20, CTBP1-DT, GMDS, MED27, TGFBRAP1, ZNF671, DDX55, HNRNPF, IDH1, PRKAA2, MBNL1, NUDCD1, BET1, TMEM167B, HOXC9, BBS10, SNX10, DCAF4, COMMD7, WASF3, TERF1, DCAF6, CCDC159, SNX8, BAK1, RBBP9, SFT2D1, TPRG1L, PAQR7, MMACHC, PAFAH2, LTO1, VPS37B, FPGS, FZD6, ASPHD1, STX2, MALL, FGFR1OP, CPLANE1, CENPJ, DTX2, LRBA, RPAP3, MKRN2, RTL8B, YIPF1, CMBL, RBFA, SHQ1, BTBD6, TMEM99, TMOD2, NDEL1, AC147067.1, LRRC23, MGAT3, MED20, DCAF12, ABCA1, GJC1, RABL2B, UXT, ANGPTL2, ZSCAN9, CREBL2, MDM1, NBPF26, MOB1B, AP4S1, LINC01278, DPH7, USP54, ZNF439, FNDC1, PCCA-DT, SLC2A11, RAB2B, LMNB1, SHROOM1, LARP1B, FUT11, RFC4, AC004158.1, RALGAPA2, TBC1D19, ITGAX, GRIPAP1, CAPN10, CASK, MEG9, MTG2, TMEM250, SLC46A1, GINS4, INTS2, STRN, NIPA1, SELPLG, CCDC88A, SLAIN2, AC005306.1, AC005899.8, TOB2, TDRD3, ITGA1, ARPIN, ENG, CCDC82, FXYD7, ZNF672, CIB2, AC003991.2, F12, ABHD16A, ZNF117, TRAF2, PYGO2, DNAJC18, SATB2-AS1, ENTPD5, SENP7, TUT4, KCTD12, LMCD1-AS1, GMFB, MTTP, TMPRSS2, NUDT15, ZNF777, ARNTL, TMEM240, GPATCH4, JAKMIP2-AS1, KALRN, SHROOM3, GPD2, CBX4, SCAF8, ZNF300, ATG2A, ESM1, H6PD, DDX18, ACTN2, GTSE1, BRAP, NUDT12, ARMC8, GLRX2, TOP3A, CNKSR3, LINC00511, RAMAC, AC080038.1, RTN2, SBSPON, ACTR10, PIEZO2, HOMER1, AC009549.1, CNKSR2, PCDHB7, UTP11, LSM6, GEN1, TMEM177, TMEM108, C12orf73, GRIK3, ACSF2, RFXAP, ADA2, PEX11G, COG6, ZNF431, ALDH2, PNPT1, ARHGAP12, ZNF629, MYH11, RASAL2, CPS1, DTD2, RYK, ASTN2, EFNB1, FCGBP, ULK2, SYPL2, HLA-C, EIF2S2, TFAM, CTNNA2, FAM162B, NSUN4, RXYLT1, POT1, MAPRE3, CDAN1, RNASEH1-AS1, MICALL1, KLHDC10, CAV2, DMAC2, ZBTB38, CTU2, YWHAB, CD200, ECE2, SNX12, SPA17, CCDC93, PRPF4B, ANO10, AC084198.2, ATG7, TATDN1, B4GALNT1, ZFAND2B, NOL6, HIBCH, ZNF883, PYM1, DIMT1, BX664615.2, SEC24A, PRKD1, SNTB2, SLC39A4, TMEM97, WDR74, VAV2, COG3, LSM14B, STIMATE, ST3GAL5, VTI1B, SNHG20, SLC10A3, TMEM254, SHISA6, FAN1, FYCO1, NEO1, BCL2L2, PCNX1, EEF1AKMT2, SOD2, MRPS2, SLC9A5, TSEN2, AC040169.1, KDR, TGFB2, TMEM138, KANK1, MYH7, POM121C, ZNF865, ITGA11, MSH6, SLC6A1, BICD2, TRA2A, ABCA6, FAM222B, IQGAP2, ZNF347, NKIRAS1, TRIM38, MTA2, SLC26A10, TDG, BICRA, NPM1, ZCCHC14, PVR, IBTK, LINC00623, WDFY1, FBLN5, ZNF585B, VPS33B, AC009133.1, C2orf27A, MIGA2, WDR75, FAM174A, PIP4K2C, WASHC2C, ZNF267, ZBTB42, LEMD1, EPM2AIP1, RP2, S1PR5, SOX12, CENPH, MTHFS, WDR5, C2orf72, TNIK, TMEM120B, ANKMY2, GLRA2, GEMIN4, VPS50, CHML, VASH1-AS1, CCDC102A, SLC66A1L, KLHL7, SMIM15, SAP130, BYSL, TOX, ZNF277, C7orf26, XPNPEP3, PRKAA1, UBXN2B, BUB1, CHST15, BRINP1, GLRB, DDX46, EID2, AC007098.1, FBLN7, UMPS, IFNAR2, TTC27, EED, COX15, CPVL, NPIPB2, DNAH1, OSBPL10, DKC1, NOC4L, PGP, OSER1-DT, NDRG3, LMLN, FAM169A, HAT1, ELFN1, LDLRAD3, SUMO1, REPS1, OLFML2A, SGO1, ZNF483, REEP4, MIER2, NME7, ZNF263, RAB4A, AC067852.2, SLC35B3, ZNF436-AS1, STX17, CASTOR1, SEMA6C, PELI1, TOX4, TMEM168, ACYP1, GRIK2, ITM2C, LPGAT1, DUBR, RRNAD1, RBM45, HEBP2, MED17, ASF1A, LIPH, RALB, SLC25A40, HIF1AN, CBX8, FKBP14, CDPF1, UFL1, NUP205, MINDY1, ECD, ARHGAP5, CNST, ZDHHC21, FAM181A, AL355974.2, TMEM47, DDHD2, KRT7, NSDHL, DPH5, ALAD, AC011451.3, SDAD1, TTYH2, CNDP2, CASP6, NKIRAS2, NHLRC2, LTB4R, MDFI, ZNF451, GABPB1-AS1, UCHL3, ACSF3, TTC21A, RNF216, CDC42, LTBP1, FBXL7, POLR3C, SERHL2, MITD1, FAM160A2, PLGLB1, APC, RAD18, AC074212.1, SP6, RAB8A, ABCD1, FBXO38, KIF7, COLEC11, URB1-AS1, C15orf39, DGKQ, A4GALT, ZNF506, ARHGAP11A, ALKBH6, NDUFAF2, SFI1, RPIA, CEP89, CLN6, DPH2, SETD6, CRIPAK, ZNF213-AS1, SOCS2, SLC7A11, JOSD1, PODXL2, ZFYVE26, SYAP1, TWIST2, SNX2, GUCY1A2, TDO2, ZNF224, ZNF549, CLPX, NCAPD3, EFCAB2, KIF3C, TOP3B, TAPT1, FRMD6, AATF, UTP18, DBR1, ENTPD4, GCFC2, RABGEF1, GRHPR, STX18, SEC23IP, CYP2J2, GLIS2, MAPKAPK3, MGRN1, RIC8B, GOLGA6L9, ERAP1, PLEKHG4B, MTMR1, CNOT6, CD58, PROSER1, BMP7, AACS, SH2B2, MICU2, SIRT6, CARD16, REXO1, CBLN4, PDHX, ANKRA2, TTC13, PTPN21, RB1CC1, GORAB, ZNF502, THAP11, KAT7, TARS2, NCOA4, C1orf50, PJA1, PABPC4, MAML1, CPXM1, AP5S1, TEF, WDR48, KLHL21, FOPNL, HMCES, AQP4, C1orf35, URI1, DDX25, PEX16, MAP1LC3B, MIIP, RUFY1, TMOD3, FAM106A, CELSR1, NEMP1, ZKSCAN5, LINC01060, C2CD5, UBE3B, KTN1, DOK4, PDS5B, LINC01197, CCDC97, ENO3, SNX33, ATG12, UEVLD, RFX5, LINC00339, RUBCNL, AC008906.2, STAT6, PDP1, DYRK3, RAB23, FMR1, CUL3, SDF2L1, NUP98, KCTD13, INPP5K, ZNF414, G3BP2, SLC25A28, PNKP, ANGEL2, SIN3A, SMIM13, SPATA2, RSRC1, SMARCAL1, IFI44, UBR3, CARD8, BEAN1, DHX33, CEBPD, OCLN, ATP11A, STEAP2, ASF1B, LDAH, WDR91, AGPAT5, KIF3A, CXADR, DTX1, HOXA-AS2, TMEM164, FUZ, USP13, AAAS, MARCH9, FAM219B, SPAG7, SC5D, COA3, SLC35A1, NDUFS6, FAM131A, STK36, TRAM2, CHKB, BUD23, PORCN, TMED1, VPS4A, ANKRD11, LRP5, ELK4, SEPTIN2, CCDC92, TTLL12, FBXO11, ITGB8, PIGH, USP22, UBE2Q1, ARHGEF1, SLC16A1, GHITM, USP5, SND1, PTRHD1, POLDIP2, NRDC, SLC27A1, DNAJB2, B3GALT6, ATPAF1, HLA-DOA, MRPL36, RMND5B, APEH, REEP6, QSER1, PPP2R5C, CARS2, FOXD1, USB1, TWF1, ZKSCAN1, GSAP, WDR90, BROX, RP9, EME2, WNK1, SLC30A5, TTLL1, LDB3, YIPF4, MFN2, PRPS2, IGF1R, THUMPD3, TBC1D9B, ZCRB1, IWS1, MIEF1, ATP6V1H, FCGRT, ISCU, MMADHC, EI24, BTBD1, SYVN1, DICER1, CNR1, ARSD, LINC01426, SMG5, MDM4, CTBP1, SLC4A3, AIMP2, ELK1, MEN1, ZDHHC20, SACM1L, ACSS3, DCTD, UBL4A, MDGA1, OAF, TBCA, ARMC7, IMMT, FNTB, ORAI2, STARD7, RARA-AS1, MRPS33, HFE, SOX8, CENPU, ACOT13, ARPC1A, WDR45, DCLK1, TM9SF4, COPG1, SLC39A14, HDAC3, COG4, LYPLA2, PRDX2, FZR1, GALC, OSBP, FAM199X, GLYR1, CKAP5, BAALC-AS2, PSMD4, RNF13, RAB11FIP3, MTOR, ZNF528, GLT8D1, TJP1, DNAJC14, ZNF384, E2F4, PDRG1, GIPC1, XPC, MAGED2, CENPT, SMIM29, G6PD, SLC35E2A, IP6K2, YIF1B, SNX19, OIP5-AS1, BOLA3, CBY1, HSD17B4, LINC01608, AC024075.2, TIMM17A, IKBKG, TM7SF2, ALG14, CAT, LIPE-AS1, BBS1, ARF3, SNF8, TXNDC12, LNPK, SLC25A16, RPTOR, FAM135A, GATD3B, SMU1, AC021242.3, IMPAD1, SRRT, ZYG11B, CPNE5, DDX1, PAQR4, NEK4, NEURL4, LEF1-AS1, POGK, SUCLA2, SYNJ2BP, POGLUT3, TCEA1, CYP2R1, MDN1, SLC12A7, FBXO9, USP11, C2orf74, RAB5C, RNF170, NDUFA2, DIS3L, SEC16A, BRPF3, PEX11B, TOMM40, CDCA4, TM9SF1, MRM2, FKBP1B, UROD, DGKZ, EPHA2, ASPSCR1, TMEM106B, POLG, ASPH, TFG, RARG, ATP13A2, PCGF3, EHBP1L1, GPX7, BTN2A1, WDR55, OLFM2, CPSF3, MPP5, ATRN, ACP6, NARS, USE1, ERAP2, RETREG3, GUCD1, DHX38, DHX32, ARL6IP4, RBM14, CDC16, ST3GAL2, PRPSAP1, ANKRD17, C11orf24, XPO5, MXRA7, INTS3, CUL5, MCM3, MFSD14B, SEC31A, PRADC1, CERK, RRP7A, RBM23, RPS26, TGFBR2, CDC42BPB, SLC39A3, SYNM, CDS2, BACE1, ATF6, EDEM2, DNAAF5, UPF1, PLEKHG1, CLCN6, KLHDC3, CMTR1, AC092957.1, PPA2, HEATR5A, DARS, ATP6V1G1, DLAT, RTCA, MCRS1, RARS2, ANK3, TMEM167A, SPACA9, ASXL1, CAMKK2, MED14, OLA1, NLGN2, RNASEH2C, EXOSC6, RDH11, RPS10, TMEM39B, SPIDR, RPL3, LARS, UNC5CL, SUOX, EVI5L, IFT52, ESS2, RIC8A, AP2A1, DPY19L4, ABCA8, ENTR1, ZNF503-AS2, FUNDC1, UNKL, SIX1, MRPL3, VIRMA, DUT, C8orf82, WASHC3, PTPRE, LIN7C, CLNS1A, SLC35F5, C8orf76, MSI2, ESCO2, MSTO1, IK, ELP4, FAM200B, YLPM1, DHRS11, TMEM87A, AKT3, SRCAP, PABPC1, NUCKS1, CCNB1IP1, MRPL4, EBAG9, SMIM10L1, CCDC25, SH3GLB1, DYNC2H1, SLC35A4, PTGR2, PEX13, MIEN1, CTTN, PSPC1, VPS45, RRN3, SNRPA1, SLC9A3-AS1, RAB43, SPRED3, SLC66A1, ADAM17, C1orf131, DERL2, ASB6, TFE3, GTF2F1, OGFR, LGR4, ABHD6, FNBP4, KNOP1, NUP62, B4GALT6, C7orf25, NUDT9, PRKD2, FUCA2, CDK5, SLC25A22, ANAPC13, SUCO, ERO1B, C11orf71, PEX12, MPDZ, ALDH16A1, SLC30A6, TMBIM1, HAUS7, BCL2L1, SPG7, UFD1,"
my_list = as.list(strsplit(my_string, ","))
my_list
length(my_list)
```

It will result in a list with length 1 [image: output] meaning a list with one element. However, I want that the list will have length(the number of strings) so that it should be my_list = as.list("SNHG12", "SYT1", "PTPRO", ...). How I can do that?

**Update**

Following the suggestion of the commentator below, I have tried using it to apply to my string as follows:

```
my_string = "MTX3, ZNF623, VEPH1, GCLM, ALS2, MAP3K3, CRIP3, GNL2, RAPGEFL1, RAD54B, GCDH, WASF1, PLEKHA2, TNFRSF21, CNNM3, GTF2E2, SNHG5, NTNG1, CHL1-AS2, PALM2-AKAP2, FGFBP3, DHRSX, LNPEP, ISY1, MTERF3, ZNF780A, CCDC24, MCHR1, GTF2H1, AURKA, TYRO3, SLC31A1, RARA, NKD2, SLC25A24, AC087477.2, EID2B, NCALD, TYW3, LUZP1, VXN, RECQL4, AC027307.2, TAF1, ZFP91, TCOF1, GCLC, PPP1R12A, SLC22A18, ZNF28, AC078846.1, TMEM109, MAIP1, TRPC5OS, AEBP2, PGAM2, PPARD, TENT4A, RGS20, ANKRD35, RGS3, VPS53, MMP2, UBE2O, NUMB, AC092069.1, ARHGEF10, AURKB, TSEN54, MLPH, GPATCH8, SMURF1, TBC1D1, SNX7, AC118549.1, PRPS1, HIST2H2BE, KATNAL1, MCL1, BCL7A, SOCS4, ADPGK, ZNF667, CSNK1G3, FBXO45, APEX2, ADRA2B, SNAPC3, MIPEP, DISC1, SCAF11, AC010198.2, ZSCAN16, HPS1, ST7-AS1, SHKBP1, AC012615.1, ACKR3, FER, OSBPL7, SEC11C, SLC1A5, ZBTB44, RPUSD2, ME1, RIN2, STRN3, VIPAS39, KIF20A, PPM1M, ELMOD3, CTR9, TTC30A, TAF4, ASCC1, TOMM40L, ZNF853, SBF2, ABCF1, CXorf38, KDM3B, PLTP, SNX29, VLDLR, MEOX2, PPM1J, CLN3, UBQLN1, NIP7, ANKLE2, ZNF761, GTF3C3, VANGL2, POLR3F, ZCCHC9, NPAS2, HAS2, HS3ST3A1, METTL2B, USP40, AL139289.2, GDF15, MCMBP, UBOX5, C2orf81, LINC01551, TOE1, CA8, SRXN1, RNF207, KIAA0556, IL1R1, GID4, MAMLD1, ZNF319, ZBTB8A, CCDC58, STK32B, IL31RA, PM20D2, TEX2, RFX7, CAMK2N2, JPT1, PGGHG, PCDHB10, MRS2, KAT14, ZNF426, TCAF1, ZBTB45, DPH3, VPS37A, DLX1, YAF2, PACRGL, MED12L, NBPF11, AC026979.2, HSPA14.1, NR2E1, CACNA1E, RIPPLY1, TBX15, AC079922.2, PRPSAP2, ALAS1, TRIM32, MAP11, RTF1, NAP1L3, PPHLN1, GFOD2, AK4, DNAJB5, IMMP2L, NOP2, CRB2, SNHG18, ZNHIT6, CKAP2, SMAD4, ZNF140, BDH1, RFWD3, DYRK1A, ALDH4A1, IFI27, CCNO, DIPK1A, ZNHIT2, LARGE1, ALDH1L1-AS2, DCP1A, HMMR, DHRS7B, GALNT5, INPP5E, FRG1, FGFR3, CLK4, LONRF1, SHF, RFX2, ZNF385D, ZSCAN32, P4HA1, ZCCHC17, MIR34AHG, NSMCE4A, HJURP, BMPR1A, SAMD11, PSMB10, UBE2W, AC092119.3, SEC24D, LINC00662, CASP7, MBTD1, TMEM163, TPM3, TMEM126B, AKT3-IT1, FAM50B, TRAIP, SOX1-OT, PIK3CA, AP3M2, RNF111, RERGL, AZIN1-AS1, PTPN14, CRYBG3, RNF123, IGSF9B, EBF2, GTPBP2, SETD4, PFKP, MED22, IL11, METTL23, ZFPM1, C16orf95, SF3B5, ARHGEF4, HTRA3, TTC28, NTRK3, POLR3E, KLC2, STRBP, NLE1, AC234582.1, ARHGEF11, CFAP44, MAPK7, SLC35A3, RIT2, NKAIN3-IT1, MROH6, MBD1, CUL2, HABP4, USPL1, LIG1, SMARCA2, ITPRIPL1, AC104964.4, KLHL8, LHFPL2, CDC42SE1, NUF2, SLC35E3, INSIG2, ZNF20, RBSN, TEPSIN, UNC119, THSD1, RORB, MCTP1, ZNF668, RFC1, IFI6, MRPL45, KLHL29, TTC39B, SEC22A, IKZF4, CHAF1A, NCKAP5L, OGFRL1, NET1, C17orf75, SLC7A1, PROX1, GEMIN5, ST7, IRF2BP1, MEGF10, NUP37, TYSND1, DYRK4, POLA2, AIM2, JMJD4, PHLDB3, KLF12, KCTD6, ERMAP, NPR2, LRRC42, NFIC, PRKAR1B, MFSD14C, NR2F1-AS1, SRGAP2, THOC2, HYMAI, FBXO46, TBC1D15, FZD2, CYP7B1, HOXA6, CDK7, FBXO25, ATP10B, BTD, ATIC, TMEM245, FAM229A, INF2, FAM207A, GINS1, SOCS6, ILRUN, STXBP4, GAREM2, XKR8, APOLD1, CDH10, TMEM265, ZSCAN5A, ICK, E2F1, NR1H4, CTPS2, NELL2, CEP41, NIF3L1, HAUS1, AC018521.5, AVL9, AC010649.1, BAIAP2L1, ST7L, AVEN, HSPA12A, SGIP1, C12orf49, ARMC9, MRPS30, PYGO1, C19orf54, TSTD3, ZNF544, HAUS6, RAB32, TSPAN10, GALE, PRUNE1, LRRC37A3, SOCS7, TRUB1, TRIM13, SEC23A, MED4, C1orf53, RBMS2, QSOX2, ORC3, CEND1, PLVAP, RSRP1, STXBP3, RAD54L2, PHLPP2, BX255925.3, RNF135, RNF41, SCAMP2, ATL2, DHX29, RFX3, SMYD2, PARP16, RAB4B, ADAMTS13, SMYD3, DHRS12, PIAS4, DIP2C, CCN4, ZCCHC8, TEAD3, RC3H2, OAS3, GPR173, FGGY, ISCA1, TSPO, GAPVD1, NDUFAF7, ZNF691, CDC7, ADCY9, UBAP1L, MRRF, PHAX, CNIH2, RPS6KB1, SMC6, NOP9, SP3, LMO7, JUP, TMEM8B, CEP131, PCGF1, TYW1, TMOD1, RNASE4, LRRC28, RFK, HSPB11, ALKBH4, HNMT, MYLK, GLIPR1L2, BNIP2, PPME1, NPAS1, MPPE1, SOX9-AS1, TRIM44, ZNF106, CARMIL1, CISD2, SLC41A2, ASL, THNSL2, METAP2, LINC00323, ZNF217, FBXW4, YAE1, EXD3, SESN1, GAL3ST1, TMEM80, GNL3L, TBC1D13, INTS8, SLITRK5, WDR20, THBD, TLR4, CNTNAP3B, KLK10, NEK2, NDUFAF6, LPCAT4, ZNF398, TMEM104, PPP4R3B, FARS2, PDGFRL, C17orf80, EBLN3P, CCNY, TRIM25, CALHM2, NR1H3, LIMD1, HOMER3, LRRC8D, BTBD10, CHST11, ZNF136, ZADH2, ERCC6L2, ZNF74, CAPS, TRIM37, ACBD3, PIGP, POLR3K, PIGB, CCDC138, ZNF582-AS1, AGER, TIMELESS, VPS36, HAX1, GPRASP2, KIF14, ABCB7, HOXC4, RBM47, TXNL1, TP53INP2, AHNAK2, SFRP1, AGBL3, UBXN11, CEP76, PKDCC, IRS1, EHD4, ZBTB9, AGL, ABITRAM, FBXW9, TMCO4, BAG2, PTPRD-AS1, MAP1A, STARD4, POLR3G, UTP20, CTBP1-DT, GMDS, MED27, TGFBRAP1, ZNF671, DDX55, HNRNPF, IDH1, PRKAA2, MBNL1, NUDCD1, BET1, TMEM167B, HOXC9, BBS10, SNX10, DCAF4, COMMD7, WASF3, TERF1, DCAF6, CCDC159, SNX8, BAK1, RBBP9, SFT2D1, TPRG1L, PAQR7, MMACHC, PAFAH2, LTO1, VPS37B, FPGS, FZD6, ASPHD1, STX2, MALL, FGFR1OP, CPLANE1, CENPJ, DTX2, LRBA, RPAP3, MKRN2, RTL8B, YIPF1, CMBL, RBFA, SHQ1, BTBD6, TMEM99, TMOD2, NDEL1, AC147067.1, LRRC23, MGAT3, MED20, DCAF12, ABCA1, GJC1, RABL2B, UXT, ANGPTL2, ZSCAN9, CREBL2, MDM1, NBPF26, MOB1B, AP4S1, LINC01278, DPH7, USP54, ZNF439, FNDC1, PCCA-DT, SLC2A11, RAB2B, LMNB1, SHROOM1, LARP1B, FUT11, RFC4, AC004158.1, RALGAPA2, TBC1D19, ITGAX, GRIPAP1, CAPN10, CASK, MEG9, MTG2, TMEM250, SLC46A1, GINS4, INTS2, STRN, NIPA1, SELPLG, CCDC88A, SLAIN2, AC005306.1, AC005899.8, TOB2, TDRD3, ITGA1, ARPIN, ENG, CCDC82, FXYD7, ZNF672, CIB2, AC003991.2, F12, ABHD16A, ZNF117, TRAF2, PYGO2, DNAJC18, SATB2-AS1, ENTPD5, SENP7, TUT4, KCTD12, LMCD1-AS1, GMFB, MTTP, TMPRSS2, NUDT15, ZNF777, ARNTL, TMEM240, GPATCH4, JAKMIP2-AS1, KALRN, SHROOM3, GPD2, CBX4, SCAF8, ZNF300, ATG2A, ESM1, H6PD, DDX18, ACTN2, GTSE1, BRAP, NUDT12, ARMC8, GLRX2, TOP3A, CNKSR3, LINC00511, RAMAC, AC080038.1, RTN2, SBSPON, ACTR10, PIEZO2, HOMER1, AC009549.1, CNKSR2, PCDHB7, UTP11, LSM6, GEN1, TMEM177, TMEM108, C12orf73, GRIK3, ACSF2, RFXAP, ADA2, PEX11G, COG6, ZNF431, ALDH2, PNPT1, ARHGAP12, ZNF629, MYH11, RASAL2, CPS1, DTD2, RYK, ASTN2, EFNB1, FCGBP, ULK2, SYPL2, HLA-C, EIF2S2, TFAM, CTNNA2, FAM162B, NSUN4, RXYLT1, POT1, MAPRE3, CDAN1, RNASEH1-AS1, MICALL1, KLHDC10, CAV2, DMAC2, ZBTB38, CTU2, YWHAB, CD200, ECE2, SNX12, SPA17, CCDC93, PRPF4B, ANO10, AC084198.2, ATG7, TATDN1, B4GALNT1, ZFAND2B, NOL6, HIBCH, ZNF883, PYM1, DIMT1, BX664615.2, SEC24A, PRKD1, SNTB2, SLC39A4, TMEM97, WDR74, VAV2, COG3, LSM14B, STIMATE, ST3GAL5, VTI1B, SNHG20, SLC10A3, TMEM254, SHISA6, FAN1, FYCO1, NEO1, BCL2L2, PCNX1, EEF1AKMT2, SOD2, MRPS2, SLC9A5, TSEN2, AC040169.1, KDR, TGFB2, TMEM138, KANK1, MYH7, POM121C, ZNF865, ITGA11, MSH6, SLC6A1, BICD2, TRA2A, ABCA6, FAM222B, IQGAP2, ZNF347, NKIRAS1, TRIM38, MTA2, SLC26A10, TDG, BICRA, NPM1, ZCCHC14, PVR, IBTK, LINC00623, WDFY1, FBLN5, ZNF585B, VPS33B, AC009133.1, C2orf27A, MIGA2, WDR75, FAM174A, PIP4K2C, WASHC2C, ZNF267, ZBTB42, LEMD1, EPM2AIP1, RP2, S1PR5, SOX12, CENPH, MTHFS, WDR5, C2orf72, TNIK, TMEM120B, ANKMY2, GLRA2, GEMIN4, VPS50, CHML, VASH1-AS1, CCDC102A, SLC66A1L, KLHL7, SMIM15, SAP130, BYSL, TOX, ZNF277, C7orf26, XPNPEP3, PRKAA1, UBXN2B, BUB1, CHST15, BRINP1, GLRB, DDX46, EID2, AC007098.1, FBLN7, UMPS, IFNAR2, TTC27, EED, COX15, CPVL, NPIPB2, DNAH1, OSBPL10, DKC1, NOC4L, PGP, OSER1-DT, NDRG3, LMLN, FAM169A, HAT1, ELFN1, LDLRAD3, SUMO1, REPS1, OLFML2A, SGO1, ZNF483, REEP4, MIER2, NME7, ZNF263, RAB4A, AC067852.2, SLC35B3, ZNF436-AS1, STX17, CASTOR1, SEMA6C, PELI1, TOX4, TMEM168, ACYP1, GRIK2, ITM2C, LPGAT1, DUBR, RRNAD1, RBM45, HEBP2, MED17, ASF1A, LIPH, RALB, SLC25A40, HIF1AN, CBX8, FKBP14, CDPF1, UFL1, NUP205, MINDY1, ECD, ARHGAP5, CNST, ZDHHC21, FAM181A, AL355974.2, TMEM47, DDHD2, KRT7, NSDHL, DPH5, ALAD, AC011451.3, SDAD1, TTYH2, CNDP2, CASP6, NKIRAS2, NHLRC2, LTB4R, MDFI, ZNF451, GABPB1-AS1, UCHL3, ACSF3, TTC21A, RNF216, CDC42, LTBP1, FBXL7, POLR3C, SERHL2, MITD1, FAM160A2, PLGLB1, APC, RAD18, AC074212.1, SP6, RAB8A, ABCD1, FBXO38, KIF7, COLEC11, URB1-AS1, C15orf39, DGKQ, A4GALT, ZNF506, ARHGAP11A, ALKBH6, NDUFAF2, SFI1, RPIA, CEP89, CLN6, DPH2, SETD6, CRIPAK, ZNF213-AS1, SOCS2, SLC7A11, JOSD1, PODXL2, ZFYVE26, SYAP1, TWIST2, SNX2, GUCY1A2, TDO2, ZNF224, ZNF549, CLPX, NCAPD3, EFCAB2, KIF3C, TOP3B, TAPT1, FRMD6, AATF, UTP18, DBR1, ENTPD4, GCFC2, RABGEF1, GRHPR, STX18, SEC23IP, CYP2J2, GLIS2, MAPKAPK3, MGRN1, RIC8B, GOLGA6L9, ERAP1, PLEKHG4B, MTMR1, CNOT6, CD58, PROSER1, BMP7, AACS, SH2B2, MICU2, SIRT6, CARD16, REXO1, CBLN4, PDHX, ANKRA2, TTC13, PTPN21, RB1CC1, GORAB, ZNF502, THAP11, KAT7, TARS2, NCOA4, C1orf50, PJA1, PABPC4, MAML1, CPXM1, AP5S1, TEF, WDR48, KLHL21, FOPNL, HMCES, AQP4, C1orf35, URI1, DDX25, PEX16, MAP1LC3B, MIIP, RUFY1, TMOD3, FAM106A, CELSR1, NEMP1, ZKSCAN5, LINC01060, C2CD5, UBE3B, KTN1, DOK4, PDS5B, LINC01197, CCDC97, ENO3, SNX33, ATG12, UEVLD, RFX5, LINC00339, RUBCNL, AC008906.2, STAT6, PDP1, DYRK3, RAB23, FMR1, CUL3, SDF2L1, NUP98, KCTD13, INPP5K, ZNF414, G3BP2, SLC25A28, PNKP, ANGEL2, SIN3A, SMIM13, SPATA2, RSRC1, SMARCAL1, IFI44, UBR3, CARD8, BEAN1, DHX33, CEBPD, OCLN, ATP11A, STEAP2, ASF1B, LDAH, WDR91, AGPAT5, KIF3A, CXADR, DTX1, HOXA-AS2, TMEM164, FUZ, USP13, AAAS, MARCH9, FAM219B, SPAG7, SC5D, COA3, SLC35A1, NDUFS6, FAM131A, STK36, TRAM2, CHKB, BUD23, PORCN, TMED1, VPS4A, ANKRD11, LRP5, ELK4, SEPTIN2, CCDC92, TTLL12, FBXO11, ITGB8, PIGH, USP22, UBE2Q1, ARHGEF1, SLC16A1, GHITM, USP5, SND1, PTRHD1, POLDIP2, NRDC, SLC27A1, DNAJB2, B3GALT6, ATPAF1, HLA-DOA, MRPL36, RMND5B, APEH, REEP6, QSER1, PPP2R5C, CARS2, FOXD1, USB1, TWF1, ZKSCAN1, GSAP, WDR90, BROX, RP9, EME2, WNK1, SLC30A5, TTLL1, LDB3, YIPF4, MFN2, PRPS2, IGF1R, THUMPD3, TBC1D9B, ZCRB1, IWS1, MIEF1, ATP6V1H, FCGRT, ISCU, MMADHC, EI24, BTBD1, SYVN1, DICER1, CNR1, ARSD, LINC01426, SMG5, MDM4, CTBP1, SLC4A3, AIMP2, ELK1, MEN1, ZDHHC20, SACM1L, ACSS3, DCTD, UBL4A, MDGA1, OAF, TBCA, ARMC7, IMMT, FNTB, ORAI2, STARD7, RARA-AS1, MRPS33, HFE, SOX8, CENPU, ACOT13, ARPC1A, WDR45, DCLK1, TM9SF4, COPG1, SLC39A14, HDAC3, COG4, LYPLA2, PRDX2, FZR1, GALC, OSBP, FAM199X, GLYR1, CKAP5, BAALC-AS2, PSMD4, RNF13, RAB11FIP3, MTOR, ZNF528, GLT8D1, TJP1, DNAJC14, ZNF384, E2F4, PDRG1, GIPC1, XPC, MAGED2, CENPT, SMIM29, G6PD, SLC35E2A, IP6K2, YIF1B, SNX19, OIP5-AS1, BOLA3, CBY1, HSD17B4, LINC01608, AC024075.2, TIMM17A, IKBKG, TM7SF2, ALG14, CAT, LIPE-AS1, BBS1, ARF3, SNF8, TXNDC12, LNPK, SLC25A16, RPTOR, FAM135A, GATD3B, SMU1, AC021242.3, IMPAD1, SRRT, ZYG11B, CPNE5, DDX1, PAQR4, NEK4, NEURL4, LEF1-AS1, POGK, SUCLA2, SYNJ2BP, POGLUT3, TCEA1, CYP2R1, MDN1, SLC12A7, FBXO9, USP11, C2orf74, RAB5C, RNF170, NDUFA2, DIS3L, SEC16A, BRPF3, PEX11B, TOMM40, CDCA4, TM9SF1, MRM2, FKBP1B, UROD, DGKZ, EPHA2, ASPSCR1, TMEM106B, POLG, ASPH, TFG, RARG, ATP13A2, PCGF3, EHBP1L1, GPX7, BTN2A1, WDR55, OLFM2, CPSF3, MPP5, ATRN, ACP6, NARS, USE1, ERAP2, RETREG3, GUCD1, DHX38, DHX32, ARL6IP4, RBM14, CDC16, ST3GAL2, PRPSAP1, ANKRD17, C11orf24, XPO5, MXRA7, INTS3, CUL5, MCM3, MFSD14B, SEC31A, PRADC1, CERK, RRP7A, RBM23, RPS26, TGFBR2, CDC42BPB, SLC39A3, SYNM, CDS2, BACE1, ATF6, EDEM2, DNAAF5, UPF1, PLEKHG1, CLCN6, KLHDC3, CMTR1, AC092957.1, PPA2, HEATR5A, DARS, ATP6V1G1, DLAT, RTCA, MCRS1, RARS2, ANK3, TMEM167A, SPACA9, ASXL1, CAMKK2, MED14, OLA1, NLGN2, RNASEH2C, EXOSC6, RDH11, RPS10, TMEM39B, SPIDR, RPL3, LARS, UNC5CL, SUOX, EVI5L, IFT52, ESS2, RIC8A, AP2A1, DPY19L4, ABCA8, ENTR1, ZNF503-AS2, FUNDC1, UNKL, SIX1, MRPL3, VIRMA, DUT, C8orf82, WASHC3, PTPRE, LIN7C, CLNS1A, SLC35F5, C8orf76, MSI2, ESCO2, MSTO1, IK, ELP4, FAM200B, YLPM1, DHRS11, TMEM87A, AKT3, SRCAP, PABPC1, NUCKS1, CCNB1IP1, MRPL4, EBAG9, SMIM10L1, CCDC25, SH3GLB1, DYNC2H1, SLC35A4, PTGR2, PEX13, MIEN1, CTTN, PSPC1, VPS45, RRN3, SNRPA1, SLC9A3-AS1, RAB43, SPRED3, SLC66A1, ADAM17, C1orf131, DERL2, ASB6, TFE3, GTF2F1, OGFR, LGR4, ABHD6, FNBP4, KNOP1, NUP62, B4GALT6, C7orf25, NUDT9, PRKD2, FUCA2, CDK5, SLC25A22, ANAPC13, SUCO, ERO1B, C11orf71, PEX12, MPDZ, ALDH16A1, SLC30A6, TMBIM1, HAUS7, BCL2L1, SPG7, UFD1"
str_as_list <- as.list(unlist(strsplit(my_string, ","), use.names = F))
length(str_as_list)
```

However, I still got the issue as follows:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"ER3, LRRC8D, BTBD10, CHST11, ZNF136, ZADH2, ERCC6L2, ZNF74, CAPS, TRIM37, ACBD3, PIGP, POLR3K, PIGB, CCDC138, ZNF582-AS1, AGER, TIMELESS, VPS36, HAX1, GPRASP2, KIF14, ABCB7, HOXC4, RBM47, TXNL
str_as_list <- as.list(unlist(strsplit(my_string, ","
```

[image: Error message] [image: error dput()]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `unlist` it you can use `as.list`

```
as.list(unlist(strsplit(my_string, ","), use.names = F))
```

The problem you are encountering is that `strsplit` already returns a list. That returned list is the same length as your input. In your example `length(my_string)` is 1. So, you are getting a list of length 1. Since you already have a list `as.list` is not doing anything.

---

**Update**

Based on the OP's comments here is code that creates a string in the format specified. There are 20,000 comma delimited strings:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

my_string <- map(1:20E3, ~ str_flatten(sample(c(LETTERS, 0:9, "."), 4, replace = T))) %>% 
  str_flatten(",")

length(my_string)
[1] 1
str_count(my_string, pattern = ",")
[1] 19999
```

The posted code works for this length:

```
str_as_list <- as.list(unlist(strsplit(my_string, ","), use.names = F))

length(str_as_list)
[1] 20000

str_as_list[1]
[[1]]
[1] "DA7W"

substr(my_string, 1, 4)
[1] "DA7W"
```

---

**Line Length**

The solutions posted answer your question. You are encountering a different issue. There is a console line length limit that you are exceeding. While R can store a string of your length, it cannot display it on one line. This is what is causing your issue.

Therefore, you need to change the way you are creating `my_string`. You cannot do a simple assignment (e.g. `my_string = "MTX3, ZNF623, ...."`). I think the following is the best option for you:

Store your string in a text file and read it into R. You can do this by pasting your string into a text file *without* the quotes like so:

[image]

Then read it in with this command: `my_string <- readLines("my_string.txt", warn = F)`. Then try the posted code.

Comment: It works only for a maximum string length of about 400. Is there any way to make it works for thousands of strings? I have about 20k strings.

Comment: @MKHuda this should work for any number of strings. I see that you posted a picture of one of your strings to Google Drive. Could you please add that string to your question? I know it is long, but you can always remove it after resolving your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I will update it. Thank you

Comment: @MKHuda I have added an update showing that the code works for strings of your length.

Comment: I still find the same issue though. For some reason, it is still error saying the same thing I posted before (Please check the comment on the previous one where I gave a drive link for the pictures)

Comment: @MKHuda I cannot replicate your issue, which is why I posted the **update**. For the `my_string` that is causing an error please copy and paste the output of `dput(my_string)` into your question so I have access to it. Then I can try replicating your issue.

Comment: I have updated it on the question. Please check.

Comment: @MKHuda As I have demonstrated, the code works for strings as long as yours. I believe the problem you are encountering is that R Markdown and the RStudio console have a line length limit that you are exceeding. This is why you are getting the `<hide>` notation at the end of your string.

Comment: So you need to change the way you are constructing this variable rather than having a very large copy and paste.

Comment: it works. I am sorry for the confusion, but what I actually want to have in the final is something like for example "AB", "abs.1", "amdn" instead of "AB" "abs.1" "amdn". I have tried to use paste(my_string, sep = ",") but does not work.

Comment: I find the solution to complete the final answer. I'll accept your answer. I am using cat(paste0('"', paste(my_string, collapse="\", \""), '"')) after following your codes and unlist it.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
string <- strsplit(my_string, split=",")[[1]]
lapply(seq_along(string), function(i) string[i])
```

Comment: If `length(my_string)` > 1 be careful explicitly selecting only the first list element with `[[1]]`. This will only get the split string for the first element of `my_string`.

Comment: @Jilber Urbina It also works only for a maximum string length of about 400. Is there any way to make it works for thousands of strings? I have about 20k strings

Comment: It works for any number of strings

Comment: @JilberUrbina I tried, but it works only about 500 strings though. Please see these https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11bstg2760SoKVAH79rMJNmMxIyU966TU?usp=sharing. I am confused.